# Why would changing a stored procedure param change the SOAP response of a web server?

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures, android-ksoap2

I have a web service built with .Net that has been running with no problems for literally years.  We recently changed the parameters of a stored procedure to accept alpha numeric values for the first parameter, and now the service is returning a SoapObject instead of a SoapPrimitive. Not only that, but the SoapObject is empty.  Running the stored procedure directly on the server (We are using SQL Server 2008 R2), runs just fine, whether or not I give it a numerical value as first parameter or an alphanumeric.

We are using ksoap in our Android App and you cannot cast a SoapObject to a SoapPrimitive, so this is causing our app to throw an Exception.

To further add to the mystery, this same web service accepts other calls to the server, calling other stored procedures that use non-numeric input as first parameter - no problems.  I unfortunately have no code to show you - our developer is trying to dig that up now.  Like I said, the webservice has been running fine for years.

Comment: Without any details this is nearly impossible to answer. Maybe somebody has run into this exact scenario but otherwise I don't see much happening.

Comment: I agree with you.  I had to try.

Comment: It is hard to deduct something without code. Can you atleast share previous SoapPrimitive response & SoapObject  response now?  Seems something to do with change in DataContract/MessageContract generated. wereyou returning primitive datatype like int, float etc without `DataContract` or `MessageContract`?